# Do I need to use NSLock?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, locks

I have an iOS class which does some calculations in a separate thread while the main thread shows an alert that allows the user to cancel the calculation. The calculation thread uses several instance variables which are accessible from both the main thread and the calculation thread. The calculation thread only ever reads these variables, and the main thread does not write or read these variables while the calculation thread exists.

My question is, to I need to lock these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as only one thread accesses them, no, you don't need to lock them.  It might be good practice to try though, and doing it now would be beneficial in case you ever do want to access them from the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "As long as only one thread accesses them..." I assume by access you mean read. If the two threads both read the variables is a lock necessary? Maybe my more general question is whether locks serve any purpose beyond synchronization? I'm a bit new to threads, and have seen all kinds of warnings about pitfalls with threads, so I'm treading very carefully.

Comment: If all threads *only* read from it, not locking it should not cause any problems.  If any one thread writes to it, all threads should lock it for both reading and writing to it.

Answer (score 2):

No you dont. You only need to lock the variables if they will be written and read from by more than one thread at a time.

Comment: That's not quite true. If you write to variables by one thread and only read from another, you still need some kind of synchronization primitive to ensure you see the writes.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Kevin, you should plan for future changes in case you need to access them.

FYI, I wouldn't use an alert, as it blocks the main view.  I recommend an activity indicator view along with an extra button that allows them to cancel.

You can do a check in each regular input control (buttons, segmented controls, etc) to make sure the app is 'not processing' in order to accept the inputs.

```
- (IBAction)someOtherButtonPressed:(id)sender {
  if( processingFlag == NO ) {
    // allow handling of input
  }
  else {
    // alert or other message indicating the app is processing
  }
}
```